# Any book overviews the ideas to reach/colonize/terraform Mars?

Tags: mars

I'm recently looking for such a (popular) book(s), that would summarize the currently developed/planned/considered ideas.

Zubrin's "Case for Mars" is a whole book just about one proposal (but of course also give some overview on others).

When reading internet, there are much more, very often very interesting ideas, but are they somewhere gathered?

(moved from https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/32895/any-book-overviews-the-ideas-to-reach-colonize-terraform-mars)

Comment: Tomasz, resource requests where the scope is not very limited are usually closed here. Resource requests in general face an uphill battle, but if you'd like to give it a shot you can try giving more specifications to limit the number of possible answers. Browsing through [this list](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22colonize%22+%22mars%22), I see a few right away that meet your current criteria, which tells me that the close-voters may be right that this is too broad as is.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to love the Red Mars, Green Mars, and Blue Mars books by Kim Stanley Robinson.

It's like history books on the colonisation of mars that fell through a portal back in time to today.

Although fiction, and only one way to do it, they are nonetheless chock full of hard science.